# xcode4 template format question

Tags: templates, format, xcode4

xcode4 uses new format for project templates (xctemplate). With existing templates I was able to get everything I needed except adding a file into the project without copying it. I need all the projects created from my template to use shared resource, so I could update all projects at once updating just one file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try hard link to the file from your template directory?